# Download file with php after login with php code

Tags: laravel, download

i have two links
one for login (www.xxx/login/)
one for download file (www.xxx/download/)

if already login, link to www.xxx/download/ will download file automatically,
if not the page will redirect to www.xxx/login/

So how can i write the php code? to login first then go to download file

Comment: please provide code that you have attempted

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Laravel provided login functionality then this is default provided by Laravel.

You can check this here

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers
```

This is the `trait` and check function `sendLoginResponse`. Below is the code written in `sendLoginResponse` function:-

```
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

If you are using custom login functionality follow this.

Comment: are you serious dude. Yo just need to add the middleware to the controller inside `_construct` method

Comment: @Manojkiran.A why you prefer to add middleware, if Laravel provide us this with Login. Instead of create new middleware and add in `__consturct` use Login to redirect to requested url.

Comment: if you have created the controller without the middlware means that any of the user who is visiting your website may access the any resource without restriction. in the above question he just need to allows on the users is authenticated

Comment: @Manojkiran.A read question again. He has pdf url which is only accessible by authenticated user. Then how can any user access that url if I he put url inside `auth` middleware. I think you have to read question once again :P

Comment: if the user is logged in the auth middlleware will return true and next methods will accessible.He is asking that only the logged in user needs to dowload the file am i right

Comment: let me clear you, we have route group with `auth` middleware. If I will move my pdf downoad route will inside that group route. then that case, we have not need to write any code in `__construct` function. If that provide me authorization process then why I will write extra code. Getting my point?

Comment: yes you are right i have also give answer for that as Closure method(Route)

Answer (score 0):

you just need the middleware

so add the `_construct` method in top of controller

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function dowloadMethod($fileName)
        {
//your code    
        }
```

if You are using the `Closure` method in route

```
Route::get('YourdowloadUrl/{fileName}',function($fileName)
{
//yourcode goesrhere
}
)->middleware(['web', 'auth']);
```